# What is DDOS TCP KILL?

Tags: network, attacks, denial-of-service, tcp

I've recently been introduced to Kali Linux's **webkiller** tool, located in the **websploit** category. It works on the concept of [Tcpkill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpkill).

I don't understand how the DoS attack with Tcpkill works. Can someone explain it in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding what tcpkill is. [tcpkill](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpkill) is not generally used in any sort of DDoS type of attack. It is possible to use it to DoS someone, but that usually involves you being within the same network segment as them, or controlling a part of the network their data transits.

To keep it short, its a packet filter. It is designed to drop packets based on your filter criteria, which can be any of the following:

- Source IP
- Destination IP
- Source Port
- Destination Port
- Any other [tcpdump](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump) expression

The idea of webkiller is to deny web service to a user on a controlled network. That may be legitimate control, like a network admin blocking certain services. Or it might be illegitimate control, like an attacker blocking access to facebook to piss someone off.

Comment: Isn't it actually that tcpkill allows you to send requests to the server but don't require you to hold onto the connection, hence DOS. Your answer seems abit off from this.